# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection con promesas en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estaba siguiendo un tutorial de node con express. Luego de terminar una de las rutas, me apareció un mensaje:

> (...) function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

El mensaje me indica que en este código

```
const newUser = new user({name, email, password})
```

debo de agregar un `catch`, pero no sé cómo agregarlo correctamente. La persona del tutorial no tuvo este problema por lo que me imagino que debe ser con las versiones recientes de node.
Adjunto todo el código de la ruta por si acaso:

```
router.post('/users/signup', async (req, res) => {
const { name, email, password, confirm_password } = req.body
const errors = []
if (name.length <= 0){
    errors.push({text: 'Please insert your name'})
}
if (password != confirm_password) {
    errors.push({text : 'password do not match'})
}
if (password.length < 4) {
    errors.push({text : 'password must be at least 4 characters long'})
}
if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render("users/signup", {errors, name, email, password, confirm_password})
} else {
    const emailUser = await User.findOne({email: email})
    if (emailUser) {
        req.flash("error_msg", "the email is already in use")
        res.redirect("/users/signup")
    }
    const newUser = new user({name, email, password})
    newUser.password = await newUser.encryptPassword(password)
    await newUser.save()
    req.flash("success_msg", "you are registered")
    res.redirect("/users/signin")
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te señala el error es que no estas manejando el posible escenario de que las promise sean rechazadas.

Al usar `async/await` una forma de capturar dicho escenario es usando `try/catch`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
try {
  const emailUser = await User.findOne({email: email})
  if (emailUser) {
    req.flash("error_msg", "the email is already in use")
    res.redirect("/users/signup")
  }
  const newUser = new user({name, email, password})
  newUser.password = await newUser.encryptPassword(password)
  await newUser.save()
  req.flash("success_msg", "you are registered")
  res.redirect("/users/signin")
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
  // código que maneja el error
}
```

Comment: También se puede usar `catch` encadenado en cada método, pero esa es otra forma, distinta a la señalada por el mensaje de error